# ant java jar classpath problem

Tags: ant

```
<target name="results">
    <echo message="Calculating QI" />   
    <java jar="jmt.jar" fork="true" failonerror="true" maxmemory="1024m" classpath="jmt/jmt">
        <arg value="-name:KIS"/>
        <arg value="-results:CONSOLE"/>
        <arg value="../allJavas.jar"/>
    </java>
</target>
```

i want from folder tmp run jar file in folder jmt/jmt. It must be run inside jmt/jmt folder becouse of dependencies files.

i can run it like `<java jar="jmt/jmt/jmt.jar"` but then dependencies files are not ok. I try to use classpath but not working. What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `dir="jmt/jmt"` attribute to specify the folder to launch the java process in, and use `jar="jmt/jmt/jmt.jar"` to specify the jar. You probably don't need to classpath attribute at all.

See http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html

Answer (score 1):

The java ant task takes an option parameter dir="jmt/jmt" that will tell the forked VM where to execute.